# Using HttpClient in PCL

Tags: .net, xamarin, httpclient, portable-class-library

I'm using Xamarin since 2014 and I always used the Microsoft [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) for the Core project and for the platform specific projects (Android, iOS).

I also developed three utility libs (let's call them **libs**):

- Common.Core (profile 78)
- Common.Droid
- Common.IOS

This **libs** contains a lot of utilities and I use them in all my projects (let's call them **EndUserApplication**).
All of them use the Microsoft HttpClient.

Today I updated all the packages that the **libs** uses.
The problem is that now the **EndUserApplication** that uses **libs** are not able to install HttpClient from nuget.
This is the message on the Android applications:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The **EndUserApplications** reference also Common.Core and also Common.Droid so, because of Common.Core, I need the Microsoft HttpClient.

Something is definitely changed, infact the description of the Microsoft HttpClient they removed Xamarin.Android e Xamarin.Core:

[image]

What need I to do in order to make my projects work again?
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**
Installing Microsoft BCL Build Components directly it works (version 1.0.21) and it let me install Microsoft HttpClient.
If I install the client direcly, I get the error. I noticed that in this way it try to install the version 1.0.14

I updated Xamarin today, but nothing changed

Comment: Can you try installing the package directly and then see if you are able to update? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build/

Comment: Also, it would be best if you can share your version information https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684

Comment: Hi, did you happen to update Xamarin today also?

Comment: Hi guys, Open post updated

Comment: Sorry, the reason I ask was we use HttpClient in a PCL Core and after the Xamarin update today it started breaking.  I will post details if I think its similar.